# CSS reveal from corner animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to achieve an animation effect as follows:

When a banner is shown, the bottom right corner of the next banner should be visible. When you click on this corner, it should hide the current banner and reveal the next one.

My current markup is as follows:

```
<div class="banners">
    <div class="image active" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="corner"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="image" style="background-color: blue;">
        <div class="corner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS as follows: Notice I used `clip-path` to create the corner:

```
.banners {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

.image {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
}

.image.active {
     z-index: 1;
     clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 60% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.corner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.corner').click(function() {
        $('.image.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle of all the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/cqqxjjgu/

One immediate issue with this is that because I'm using `z-index` to specify that the current 'active' banner should have precedence, when remove the `active` class it just displays the next banner immediately, so ideally the `z-index` should only be changed once the animation has completed.

Does anyone have anyt idea how I can achieive this? Ideally I need a cross browser solution (not too fussed about IE < 10).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A simple example accomplishing this effect with no javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/j2159b1e/2/

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.banners {
  position:relative;
  background:#000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.banners input{
  display:none;
}
.slide1{
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT5T6nwVYWsbzLcLF-JNxnGXFFFwkZMBcCMbaqeTevuldkxHg0N);
}
.slide2{
  background-image:url(http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/02/06-train-cat-shake-hands.jpg);
}
.slide3{
  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKr6YlGNsqgJzvgBBkq1648_HsuDizVn_ZXC6iQp9kjXFzLvs1BA);
}
.image {
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  background-position:0 0;
  background-size:cover;
  transition:z-index 1s step-end;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: clipout;
}
input:checked + .image{
  z-index:3;
  transition:z-index 1s step-end;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
  animation-name: clipin;
  cursor:default;
}
.image:nth-child(2),
input:checked + * + * + .image{
  z-index:2;
  cursor:pointer;
}


.content{
  color:#FFF;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-family:arial;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:24px;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0s opacity 1s;
}
input:checked + .image .content{
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.8s opacity 0.8s;
}
.spanner{
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

@keyframes clipout {
  from { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
  50%  { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% -100%, -100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
  51%   { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
  to   { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
}
@keyframes clipin{
  from { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
  50%  { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }
  to   { clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0); }  
}
```

```html
<div class="banners">
  <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slides" checked="checked" />
  <label class="image slide1" for="slide1">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slides"  />
  <label class="image slide2" for="slide2">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 2
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slides"  />
  <label class="image slide3" for="slide3">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 3
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Basically, just use keyframes to animate the clip path. Get fancy with the z-indexes and some sibling selectors.

Comment: This looks amazing! Works very well in Firefox too. Just one request (sorry to be a pain) - is it possible to do this using just `div` tags? I don't think `input` and `label` are the most semantically correct tags for the purpose of this feature. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks again.

Comment: @GSTAR The short answer is "no". But also, screw semantics generally speaking, so long as it works. Unless you're worried about SEO maybe. In which case I might have an idea... but the simple answer there is to replace the inputs and sibling selectors with classes, and then toggle the classes using javascript kind of like your OP

Comment: Fantastic. I'll give that a go tomorrow. Also one thing I just noticed (probably should have noticed earlier) `clip-path` isn't supported in IE11 or Edge. Do you know of any similar techniques that could produce the corner shape whilst maintaining cross browser compatibility?

Comment: @GSTAR Probably looking at a similar setup but using canvas or svg

Comment: Instead of `clip-path` just `transform: skew(20deg) rotate(20deg)` and then on the children you can `transform: skew(-20deg) rotate(-20deg)` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 9):

This should work for any browser with transition support:
https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/cqqxjjgu/1/

Essentially, make a really big cover slide, with the same background color as your next slide, and pull it over your current slide. Then fade out to reveal the next slide.

So a little adjustment on the html:

```
<div class="banners">
  <div class="image active" style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
    <div class="corner" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>      
  </div>

  <div class="image" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 2
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
    <div class="corner" style="background-color: magenta;"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="image" style="background-color: magenta;">
    <div class="content">
      Slide 3
    </div>
    <div class="spanner"></div>
    <div class="corner" style="background-color: black;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change the jQuery to select either the next slide or the first if there are no more:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.corner').click(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass("active");
        if ($parent.next().length){
            $parent.next().addClass("active");
        } else {
            $parent.prevAll().last().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

And set up some intricate transitions you can adjust the timing of:

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    transition:z-index 2s step-end, 1s opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;
}
.image.active{
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
    transition:z-index 2s step-end, 0s opacity 0s;
}

.corner {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 70%,  0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 100% 0);
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:150%;
    margin-top:150%;
    transition:2s top ease-in-out, 2s left ease-in-out, 0s margin 2s;
}
.image.active .corner{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-left:0;
  transition:0s top ease-in-out 1s, 0s left ease-in-out 1s, 2s margin ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

---

**Aside:** This example is completely flexible (doesn't care about size):

```
.banners {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or with images: https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/ens7caaL/

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I can see what you've done there by setting the background colour of the corner to the same colour as the next slide. I was wondering how this could be enhanced to support background images? Ideally I don't want to put the background image as the corner, as the carousel plugin I'm using automatically resizes the images so it may not always match.

Comment: Just noticed you've created a demo with images! Fantastic! But do you reckon it could be done so that we don't have to set the background image on the corners?

Comment: thanks. If you have trouble with this, don't worry about it :) BTW I noticed your images demo doesn't properly work in Firefox. Looks like it's an issue with `background-attachment`.

Comment: @GSTAR background attachment fixed gets a little tricky. Can you provide an example of the actual images for the effect you're attempting? Is it just a background image, or will you have content as well?

Comment: Hi, they will be background images that fill the entire slide - basically how you've done it on your images demo :) There will be a `.content` div in each slide but I don't think that is likely to cause any issues.

Comment: @GSTAR well whether or not there's content is integral to how the effect is accomplished. Also, will this be "full page" or will it be a content area within a greater page?

Comment: Hi, it will be a full page carousel.

Comment: @GSTAR See my second answer then, should work more or less. Still working on a more solid version. Please give up arrow credits where due

Comment: No worries :) Yep the images demo works well in Chrome, it's just a bit buggy in Firefox.

Comment: @GSTAR Not the one in this answer, I posted a complete second answer too :)

Comment: @GSTAR Updated other answer, please see final solution. Should work quite smoothly in many situations. Can set size to anything.

Answer (score 5):

This will work everywhere, even in IE/Edge. It's based on CSS `transition`s and replacing CSS classes via JavaScript.

I'm using rotated rectangle to crop images. Demo of main principle (contains a lot of hardcoded, previously calculated values):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -86.6px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 359.8px;
  height: 240px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Main demo (there are a lot of hardcoded values). For better understanding how it works you can add `border` to `.slide-cropper`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".banners").on("click", ".slide-cropper.next .slide-content", function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest(".slide");
    
    $(".slide-cropper").removeClass("prev")
      .removeClass("current")
      .removeClass("next");

    $(this).closest(".slide-cropper").addClass("current");

    var $prevContainer;
    if ($container.prev().length) {
      $prevContainer = $container.prev();
    } else {
      $prevContainer = $container.siblings(":last");
    }
    $prevContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("prev");

    var $nextContainer;
    if ($container.next().length) {
      $nextContainer = $container.next();
    } else {
      $nextContainer = $container.siblings(":first");
    }
    $nextContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("next");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* all body styles are just for demo */
/* just centering the slider */
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banners {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide .slide-cropper {
  position: absolute;
  left: -86.6px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 359.8px;
  height: 323.2px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 2s linear;
}

.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  z-index: 0;
  
  /* just styles for text */
  /* using flexbox to center text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide1 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt875.jpg");
}

.slide2 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbmw.jpg");
}

.slide3 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UxLW.jpg");
}

.slide-cropper.prev {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.slide-cropper.current {
  height: 240px;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide-cropper.next {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Fix for IE */
.slide-cropper.current {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide slide1">
    <div class="slide-cropper current">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide2">
    <div class="slide-cropper next">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide3">
    <div class="slide-cropper">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand how it works I moved all calculations to [CSS variables AKA CSS custom properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/). They work in many browsers but not in combination with CSS `calc` function. This example works perfectly only in Chrome but will help to understand and modify this example (just replace CSS variables with calculated hardcoded values). **Also you can move this calculations to CSS preprocessor or JavaScript code.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".banners").on("click", ".slide-cropper.next .slide-content", function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest(".slide");
    
    $(".slide-cropper").removeClass("prev")
      .removeClass("current")
      .removeClass("next");

    $(this).closest(".slide-cropper").addClass("current");

    var $prevContainer;
    if ($container.prev().length) {
      $prevContainer = $container.prev();
    } else {
      $prevContainer = $container.siblings(":last");
    }
    $prevContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("prev");

    var $nextContainer;
    if ($container.next().length) {
      $nextContainer = $container.next();
    } else {
      $nextContainer = $container.siblings(":first");
    }
    $nextContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("next");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --width: 300px;
  --height: 200px;
  /* rotate for image cropping */
  --rotate-angle: 30deg;
  /* sin 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --sin-rotate-angle: 0.5;
  /* cos 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --cos-rotate-angle: 0.8660254037844386;
  /* clipper ratio for width, can be from 0 to 1 */
  --clipper-ratio: 0.45;
  --animation-timeout: 2s;
}

/* all body styles are just for demo */
/* just centering the slider */
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banners {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide .slide-cropper {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  top: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  width: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rotate-angle)));
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height var(--animation-timeout) linear;
}

.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  z-index: 0;
  
  /* just styles for text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide1 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt875.jpg");
}

.slide2 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbmw.jpg");
}

.slide3 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UxLW.jpg");
}

.slide-cropper.prev {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.slide-cropper.current {
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--clipper-ratio) * var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transition-delay: var(--animation-timeout);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide-cropper.next {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Fix for IE */
.slide-cropper.current {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide slide1">
    <div class="slide-cropper current">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide2">
    <div class="slide-cropper next">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide3">
    <div class="slide-cropper">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To change this to fullscreen you need to set `--width: 100vw` and `--height: 100vh`. (Of course, then you'll have to replace CSS variables with hardcoded values to work in all browsers). Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".banners").on("click", ".slide-cropper.next .slide-content", function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest(".slide");
    
    $(".slide-cropper").removeClass("prev")
      .removeClass("current")
      .removeClass("next");

    $(this).closest(".slide-cropper").addClass("current");

    var $prevContainer;
    if ($container.prev().length) {
      $prevContainer = $container.prev();
    } else {
      $prevContainer = $container.siblings(":last");
    }
    $prevContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("prev");

    var $nextContainer;
    if ($container.next().length) {
      $nextContainer = $container.next();
    } else {
      $nextContainer = $container.siblings(":first");
    }
    $nextContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("next");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --width: 100vw;
  --height: 100vh;
  /* rotate for image cropping */
  --rotate-angle: 30deg;
  /* sin 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --sin-rotate-angle: 0.5;
  /* cos 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --cos-rotate-angle: 0.8660254037844386;
  /* clipper ratio for width, can be from 0 to 1 */
  --clipper-ratio: 0.45;
  --animation-timeout: 2s;
}

/* all body styles are just for demo */
/* just centering the slider */
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banners {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide .slide-cropper {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  top: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  width: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(calc(-1 * var(--rotate-angle)));
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height var(--animation-timeout) linear;
}

.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate-angle));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  z-index: 0;
  
  /* just styles for text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide1 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt875.jpg");
}

.slide2 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbmw.jpg");
}

.slide3 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UxLW.jpg");
}

.slide-cropper.prev {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.slide-cropper.current {
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--clipper-ratio) * var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transition-delay: var(--animation-timeout);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide-cropper.next {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Fix for IE */
.slide-cropper.current {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide slide1">
    <div class="slide-cropper current">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide2">
    <div class="slide-cropper next">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide3">
    <div class="slide-cropper">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also demo with CSS variables that work in Firefox (Firefox is not friendly with combination of CSS variables and `transform: rotate`, so I just replaced `transform: rotate` with hardcoded values):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".banners").on("click", ".slide-cropper.next .slide-content", function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest(".slide");
    
    $(".slide-cropper").removeClass("prev")
      .removeClass("current")
      .removeClass("next");

    $(this).closest(".slide-cropper").addClass("current");

    var $prevContainer;
    if ($container.prev().length) {
      $prevContainer = $container.prev();
    } else {
      $prevContainer = $container.siblings(":last");
    }
    $prevContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("prev");

    var $nextContainer;
    if ($container.next().length) {
      $nextContainer = $container.next();
    } else {
      $nextContainer = $container.siblings(":first");
    }
    $nextContainer.find(".slide-cropper").addClass("next");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --width: 100vw;
  --height: 100vh;
  /* sin 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --sin-rotate-angle: 0.5;
  /* cos 30 degrees for image cropping */
  --cos-rotate-angle: 0.8660254037844386;
  /* clipper ratio for width, can be from 0 to 1 */
  --clipper-ratio: 0.45;
  --animation-timeout: 2s;
}

/* all body styles are just for demo */
/* just centering the slider */
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banners {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide .slide-cropper {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1 * var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  top: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  width: calc(var(--height) * var(--sin-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--cos-rotate-angle));
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height var(--animation-timeout) linear;
}

.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  left: calc(var(--height) / 2);
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  z-index: 0;
  
  /* just styles for text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.slide1 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt875.jpg");
}

.slide2 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbmw.jpg");
}

.slide3 .slide-content {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UxLW.jpg");
}

.slide-cropper.prev {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.slide-cropper.current {
  height: calc(var(--height) * var(--cos-rotate-angle) + var(--clipper-ratio) * var(--width) * var(--sin-rotate-angle));
  transition-delay: var(--animation-timeout);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide-cropper.next {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Fix for IE */
.slide-cropper.current {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide slide1">
    <div class="slide-cropper current">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide2">
    <div class="slide-cropper next">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide slide3">
    <div class="slide-cropper">
      <div class="slide-content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good work Vadim! The only thing I'd say is that there are a lot of fixed widths / heights in this. How can we ensure this looks perfect responsively? The carousel will always be 100% width and height of the viewport.

Comment: @GSTAR I know, it took a lot of time to write this and I'm planning to provide formulas shortly. There are a lot of `sin` and `cos` calculations so it will be easier to use CSS preprocessor or calculate it once and forget it.

Comment: @GSTAR Do you have any issues with my demo now?

Comment: this looks great in Chrome! In Firefox it is appearing diagonal, can you see what the issue is?

Comment: @GSTAR This is demo with CSS variables, it will work OK only in Chrome. To work it everywhere you'll have to replace CSS variables with hardcoded values. Does it makes sense for you?

Comment: In all honesty I don't think this is going to be possible because it doesn't display at all in IE or Edge. There are many places in this code where CSS variables are used and it would be difficult to change them all. Anyway I have posted a similar question here - maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165937/css-next-previous-clip-path-animation

Comment: For this to work in Firefox just replace `transform: rotate` with variable to fixed values `transform: rotate(-30deg)` and `transform: rotate(30deg)`. See working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dsg8y3e4/9/. In Firefox combination of CSS variables and `transform: rotate` doesn't work.

Comment: Also if it's hard to replace variables in CSS with hardcoded values you can move this calculations to JavaScript or to some CSS preprocessor code (LESS, Sass, SCSS etc).

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer without the use of [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility), because *browser compatibility* on DOM elements other than `svg` is low.

I see now that Vadim had the same idea as me with the rotated container (hadn't checked back here until I had finished), but from what I can tell there are still enough differences between our answers to justify posting my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").on("click",".next",function() {
    if ($(this).prev().length) {$(this).prev().removeClass("curr");} else {$(this).siblings().last().removeClass("curr");} //deactivate current slide
    if ($(this).next().length) {$(this).next().addClass("next");} else {$(this).siblings().first().addClass("next");} //prepare slide that follows next slide
    $(this).removeClass("next").addClass("curr"); //activate next slide
  });
});
```

```css
.slider, .slider .img {
  width: 55vw;
  height: calc(55vw / 16*9);
  background: #000 center/contain no-repeat;
}
.slider {position:relative; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;}

.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 250%;
  height: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transition:z-index 0s 0.7s, height 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider .slide.next {z-index:1; height:155%; opacity:0.5; transition:z-index 0s 1.1s, height 0s 0.7s; cursor:pointer;}
.slider .slide.curr {z-index:2; height:135%; opacity:1.0; transition:z-index 0s 1.1s, height 0.4s 0.7s, opacity 0.7s;}

.slider .slide .img {margin-left:50%; transform:rotate(20deg); transform-origin:0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide curr"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide next"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/people);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch);"></div></div>
</div>
```

*codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJQRvM*
*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tq2hw7b9/5/*

- Instead of `clip-path` I just change the `height` of the slide containers, using `transition` for the animation effects.

---

### IE TROUBLES

Unfortunately, as usual, IE processes [`transform:rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) differently from other browsers. Visually the rotations happen, but the browser still seems to reserve the original space of the elements, so therefor the exposed corner of the next slide is *not clickable* because the current slide is 'covering' it. Using the `-ms-` or `-webkit-` prefix doesn't make a difference.

The following **code snippet** DOES work in IE:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider .corner").on("click",function() {
   var $next = $(this).siblings(".next");
    if ($next.prev().length) {$next.prev().removeClass("curr");} else {$next.siblings(".slide").last().removeClass("curr");} //deactivate current slide
    if ($next.next(".slide").length) {$next.next().addClass("next");} else {$next.siblings().first().addClass("next");} //prepare slide that follows next slide
    $next.removeClass("next").addClass("curr"); //activate next slide
  });
});
```

```css
.slider, .slider .img {
  width: 55vw;
  height: calc(55vw / 16*9);
  background: #000 center/contain no-repeat;
}
.slider {position:relative; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden;}

.slider .corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 21%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider .slide {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 250%;
  height: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transition:z-index 0s 0.7s, height 0.7s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider .slide.next {z-index:1; height:155%; opacity:0.5; transition:z-index 0s 1.1s, height 0s 0.7s;}
.slider .slide.curr {z-index:2; height:135%; opacity:1.0; transition:z-index 0s 1.1s, height 0.4s 0.7s, opacity 0.7s;}

.slider .slide .img {margin-left:50%; transform:rotate(20deg); transform-origin:0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide curr"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide next"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/people);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);"></div></div>
  <div class="slide"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch);"></div></div>
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```

*codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEbrzQ*
*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ggqndj1/*

- I added an extra `<div class="corner">` that covers all the slides.
- The click-handler in JS is now bound to this `.corner`, and at the start of the handler a reference to the next slide is stored into a variable, which is used in the rest of the code.
- In CSS there is also a new rule for the `.corner`.

---

### SLIDE-ARRAY IN JS

Have a look at the **code snippet** below, for a list of slides in JS (if someone needs it):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = [
   2, //index for next slide
    "https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/480/people",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech",
    "https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch"
  ];
  
//INITIALIZE SLIDESHOW--------------------
  $(".slider").css("background-image","url("+slides[2]+")"); //set next slide
  $(".slider .current .img").css("background-image","url("+slides[1]+")"); //set current slide, and set slide-height to slideshow-height
  
//SLIDESHOW CLICK-HANDLER--------------------
  $(".slider .current").on("click",function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
  $(".slider").on("click",function() {
   $(this).children(".current").animate({height:0},700,function(){
     $(this).children(".img").css("background-image","url("+slides[slides[0]]+")"); //set the current slide to the next slide
     $(this).css("height","155%"); //cover entire slide
      if (slides[0]==slides.length-1) {slides[0]=1;} else {++slides[0];} //increase/loop index for next slide
      $(this).parent().css("background-image","url("+slides[slides[0]]+")"); //set the next slide to the next slide after that
      $(this).animate({height:"135%"},400); //reveal corner for next slide
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.slider, .slider .img {
  width: 55vw;
  height: calc(55vw / 16*9);
  background: #000 center/contain no-repeat;
}
.slider {margin:0 auto; cursor:pointer; overflow:hidden;}

.slider .current {
  width: 250%;
  height: 135%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-20deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
}
.slider .current .img {margin-left:50%; transform:rotate(20deg); transform-origin:0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider"><div class="current"><div class="img"></div></div></div>
```

*codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXBgew*
*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qghv9bnh/13/*

- It may hold some preferences for some, although I think my first solution is a lot cleaner, faster, and flexible for adding extra slides (certainly when you use a CMS like WordPress or Joomla):

  1. The images are only loaded when you actually use the slider, so users save bandwidth for every slide they don't click on.
  2. The HTML is very concise and will never grow no matter how many slides you have, so your HTML will look cleaner (but if you use PHP to include them it will look just as clean, even cleaner).

Can't really think of anything else, as I said, I prefer the first one. But none the less, it may come in handy for someone.

Comment: yours is the only solution that works for me also in FF from 2015 and in IE11

Comment: @myfunkyside - this is a very good solution - works cross browser too! I was just wondering do you know if this could work with another snippet at the top left corner, which would act as a "previous slide" button?

Answer (score 0):

This sample working on Firefox, Chrome, IE.

For change sliding rule change `transition`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.angle').click(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass("current");
        if ($parent.next().length){
         $parent.next().addClass("current");
        } else {
         $parent.prevAll().last().addClass("current");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.slideShow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    transition:z-index 2s step-end, 1s opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.image.current{
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
    transition:z-index 2s step-end, 0s opacity 0s;
}

.angle {
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 70%,  0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 100% 0);
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:150%;
    margin-top:150%;
    transition:2s top ease-in-out, 2s left ease-in-out, 0s margin 2s;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.image.current .angle{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-left:0;
  transition:0s top ease-in-out 1s, 0s left ease-in-out 1s, 2s margin ease-in-out 1s;
}
.main{
  color:#FFF;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-family:arial;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:24px;
}
.middle{
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:0;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.image1, .image3 .angle{
  background-image: url(http://i3.imgbus.com/doimg/4c5o0m8m6o5n4e0.png);
}
.image1 .angle, .image2{
  background-image:url(http://i4.imgbus.com/doimg/1c7obm6m1o3nbb0.png);
}
.image2 .angle, .image3{
  background-image:url(http://i3.imgbus.com/doimg/ccbo5m2m8o8n759.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="image image1 current">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="angle" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>      
  </div>

  <div class="image image2" style="background-color: cyan;">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="angle" style="background-color: magenta;"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image image3" style="background-color: magenta;">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="angle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can use SildeShow Maker softwares like [Amazing Slider](https://amazingslider.com/).

easy download, easy use: [download link](https://amazingslider.com/downloads/)

it's very powerful software. see Screenshot [image: here]