# load div diagonally on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.main_div2_sub {
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 80px 100vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #56c3b0 transparent;
}
.top_div
{
height:100px;
}
.bottomdiv
{
height:100px;
background-color:#56c3b0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_div"></div>
<div class="div2">
<div class="main_div2_sub">
 </div>
 <div class="bottomdiv"></div>
 </div>
```

I want to load div2 diagonally(wiper animation) on scrolling how can I do that.
unfortunately searching for it hasn't given me much results.

Comment: What exactly would your result look like? Do you see nothing at first and as you scroll, the content becomes visible from behind an invisible diagonal line? Or is there already content visible that is cut off by an invisible line, and as you scroll down, that line moves down, revealing more and more content? Or something else? Please describe as clear as you can, with as much detail, without making it unnecessarily long

Comment: while scrolling the second div replaces the first with an animation.that animation is like a wiper movement@ myfunkyside

Comment: I still don't get it. Note that I'm not asking how you want to implement it, I'm asking purely about the desired result here. How should the end-result look/behave to the user. Then we can (hopefully) give you adequate advice on what HTML,CSS,JS to use. That is after all where you got stuck and why you're here asking for help. *(Always provide evidence of your code so far, but never assume that code was on the right/best track)*

Comment: sorry for that.i need to give an animation which loads the second div diagonally @ myfunkyside

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/45058893/3407923](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45058893/3407923)

Comment: Thank you....it's helped me. @ myfunkyside