# CSS next & previous clip path animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, clip-path

Following on from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058893/css-reveal-from-corner-animation) that I posted last week, I have created a custom carousel that uses `clip-path` to provide a snippet of the next and previous slides. This is currently working functionally, but I now need to apply some animations when showing/hiding the slides.

In the related question, only the "next slide" functionality was needed, and a solution that was provided was to clip the "active" slide. However now since we need to do next and previous slides, I have applied the clip to the next and previous slides instead. Code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide').click(function() {
    var current = $(this);
    var prev = current.prev('.slide');
    var next = current.next('.slide');

    $('.slide').removeClass('active next prev');

    if (current.hasClass('prev')) {
      current.addClass('active').removeClass('prev');
    } else {
      current.addClass('active').removeClass('next');
    }

    if (prev.length) {
      prev.addClass('prev');
    } else {
      $('.slide:last').addClass('prev');
    }

    if (next.length) {
      next.addClass('next');
    } else {
      $('.slide:first').addClass('next');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.banners {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.active {
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide.next {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 55% 100%, 100% 67%);
}

.slide.prev {
  clip-path: polygon(44% 0, 0 30%, 0 0);
}

.slide.next,
.slide.prev {
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide .image {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.spanner {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide active">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2127/SNvipw.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide next">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6240/GzBaZq.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide prev">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/227/XRZGsI.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of all the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/795f88nm/

As you will see the carousel works fine. I just need to add in animations, as follows:

- When clicking the next slide (bottom right corner) it should gradually reveal the slide upwards. The "new" next slide should gradually appear from the bottom corner.
- When clicking the previous slide (top left corner) it should gradually reveal the slide downwards. The "new" previous slide should gradually appear from the top corner.

I'm not very good at doing animations, so could do with some help on this.

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/darjiyogen/795f88nm/1/

Comment: @yogendarji no - please see the image in my post (just added it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use `animation` with your `clip-path`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide').click(function() {
    var current = $('.slide.active');
    var prev = $('.slide.prev');
    var next = $('.slide.next');

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
      prev.removeClass('prev').addClass('next');
      current.removeClass('active').addClass('prev');
      next.removeClass('next').addClass('active');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
      next.removeClass('next').addClass('prev');
      current.removeClass('active').addClass('next');
      prev.removeClass('prev').addClass('active');
    }

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.banners {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.active {
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide.next {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 55% 100%, 100% 67%);
  animation: polygons_next 2s alternate;
}

.slide.prev {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(44% 0, 0 30%, 0 0);
  animation: polygons_prev 2s alternate;
}

@keyframes polygons_next {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 55% 100%, 100% 67%);
  }
}

@keyframes polygons_prev {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 0 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(44% 0, 0 30%, 0 0);
  }
}

.slide.next,
.slide.prev {
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide .image {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.spanner {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banners">
  <div class="slide prev">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/2127/SNvipw.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 1
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide active">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6240/GzBaZq.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 2
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide next">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img924/227/XRZGsI.jpg');">
      <div class="content">
        Slide 3
      </div>
      <div class="spanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good work @yogen! Almost there, the animation isn't quite smooth though, it just jumps.

Comment: @GSTAR yea it still requires few changes with animate property for smooth animation

Comment: No worries, I'll play around with the animations a bit. One other thing is that when clicking the "previous" slide it should animate from top to bottom. Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: @GSTAR You can set one more class to decide direction and create different animation clip-path for that set too. May be this can help to create path http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Thanks yogen. I managed to do this by adding a class to the container that tracks which direction the slider was last moved, i.e. forwards or backwards. Then using this class I was able to target two new classes that perform the downwards animation.