# CSS ease-out/ ease-in transition animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm still beginner at CSS, html and JS. I tried to do a transition ease-out for the property left, cuz I.m doing an animated galery for my future purposes. I tested it in the browser, the images where changing but the transition didn't happened.

Here is my "index.html":

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="galery">
            <img class="galery_comp" src="img/leaf.jpg">
            <img class="galery_comp" src="img/spital.jpg">
            <img class="galery_comp" src="img/nature.jpg">
            <img class="galery_comp" src="img/forest.jpg">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="back"><-- Back</button>
        <button type="button" id="next">Next --></button>
        <script src="Galery.js"></script>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my "style.css":

```
div.galery{
    display: flex;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-out; /* This is where i tried */
}

img{
    width: 600;
    height: 500;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is my "Galery.js":

```
    function Galery(){
    this.imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('galery_comp');
    this.currentImage = 0;
    this.offSet = 0;
    var hide = false;

    this.sleep = function(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
          if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
          }
    }
}

  this.init = function(){
      this.imgs[0].style.display = "block"
  }

  this.next = function(){
      this.currentImage++;
      if (this.currentImage >= this.imgs.length)
      {
          this.currentImage = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < this.imgs.length; i++){
              this.imgs[i].style.left = 0;
              this.imgs[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
      this.imgs[this.currentImage].style.display = "inline";
      this.offSet=0;
  }

  this.slideNext = function(){
      this.imgs[this.currentImage].style.left = -parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.imgs[0], null).width) - this.offSet;
      this.imgs[this.currentImage].style.display = "none";
      this.offSet = 10;
      this.next();
  }

  this.slideBack = function(){
      if (this.currentImage === 0){
          this.currentImage = this.imgs.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < this.imgs.length; i++){
              this.imgs[i].style.left = -parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(this.imgs[0], null).width);
              this.imgs[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
      this.currentImage--;
      this.imgs[this.currentImage].style.display = "inline";


      this.imgs[this.currentImage].style.left = 0;
      if (this.currentImage + 1 < this.imgs.length)
          this.imgs[this.currentImage + 1].style.display = "none";
  }
```

}

And finally here is my sketch.js:

```
    var galery = new Galery();
galery.init();

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", function(){
    galery.slideNext();
});

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener("click", function(){
    galery.slideBack();
});
```

Did i made something wrong? Or i should use another tehnique. If you want to test it you can use whatever images you want and how many you want(only keep the "galery_comp" class for the js)
Any answear apreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267732/5068056

Comment: For simplicity, I suggest you to maybe use a plugin that does what you need. Unless you want to show off your javascript skills. :)

Comment: So what plugin are you suggesting?

Comment: Do you know one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `transition` to your `img`.

Your also setting (in your js) the `display` to `none`. 
So you're basically removing the img before the transition can be seen. `display`is also a non-transitionable attribute

Instead of display, try using `opacity` and setting it to either `0 or 1` (depending wether you want to show it or not)

then you could also add a transition for your opacity (maybe differently timed) and have a nice effect)

```
img{
    width: 600;
    height: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help i saw that opacity worked but the left didn't and i think i have problems in the alghorithm ill check to see.